# How to check if a wallet owns at least one NFT within a collection

Tags: nft, balance, collection, owner

Is it possible to call something like wallet.BalanceOf(NFTCollectionId)?

I see how you can check to see if a specific account owns a specific NFT, but don’t see a way to check if the account owns at least one within a collection, or get a list of NFTs owned for a specific collection.

I see some references to metaplex that can be used to group NFT’s into a collection? But what if someone hasn’t done this? And I think this is maybe the main concern.

Id hate to recurse through N NFT’s to see if an account owns at least one to determine this.